# How to delete from a temp view or equivalent in spark sql databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I need to delete from a temp view in databricks, but it looks like i can do only merge, select and insert. Maybe i missed something but I did not find any documentation on this.

STEP 1 : Here I am creating a temp view :

```
table_df = spark.read.format('delta').load("mnt/table_path")
table_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")
```

STEP 2 :Then trying to delete :

```
%sql 
delete from table_name
where id in (1,2,3)
```

getting :

> Invalid command: 'table_name' is a view not a table.; line 1 pos 0;

STEP 3:

```
table_name_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "mnt/table_path")
last_actions = table_name_delta.history(1).collect()
```

It works well for merge, select and insert. Here a couple of constraints :

- I don't want to create a delta table to proceed with the delete because the view should not be accessible in other notebooks/clusters.
- I want to access the logs of the delta table created in STEP 3 and
  see that delete statement happened
- I have a constraint to use only a source and a destination table and
  no intermediary tables

Is it possible to delete from a view or equivalent ? Is there an equivalent of temp views that support delete ?

Answer (score 2):

Apache spark doesn't support delete action. You can achieve it by applying the filter on the data frame or create another temp table with the filtered condition.

1. Step Creating a sample DataFrame

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([("Alberto", 1), 
                              ("Dakota", 2), 
                              ("Kumar", 3),
                              ("Siva", 4),
                              ("Sree", 5),
                              ("Kavin", 6)], 
                                   ["Name", "id"])

data.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")
```

In your spark SQL you can create another view with the filtered values, as given below:

```
%sql 
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW table_name1 AS SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE id not in(1, 2);
select * from table_name1;
```

[Sample Databricks notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3347130766051599/3511601837639531/382586924100581/latest.html)

Comment: thank you Sivakumar, this solution is valid, unfortunately i cannot use it in my case. I cannot create another table as i have a constraint to use only a source and a destination table and no intermediary tables. I edited my answer.